# Atualizar registros por blocos

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Oi,

Preciso fazer um *update* em um campo (chamado *bloco*) a cada determinada quantidade de registros. Tenho 100 registros, a cada 10, devo inserir um número (automático) no campo. A ideia é dividir os registros na hora da consulta, assim:

Bloco 1 - João, Maria,... até o décimo.

Bloco 2 - Pedro, Manoel,... até o vigésimo.
etc...

Usei o exemplo de 100, mais na verdade tenho 5 mil que cresce a cada dia, então, quando eu executar determinada função - ou automáticamente, terá que começar a criar e inserir um novo bloco após os 100 registros e continuar até que seja identificado que já foram 10 atualizados, quando houver o 111 registro, já irá começar a inserir o bloco 12, no caso.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o método `COUNT` do MYSQL. Ele permite contar o número de registros de uma tabela rapidamente. Com a quantidade de registros e a quantidade de registros por bloco em mãos, a última é uma constante, podemos facilmente descobrir o bloco do cliente. Com isso, você pode inserir esse valor no banco de dados.

No exemplo abaixo, inserimos um cliente no banco e automaticamente o bloco a ele designado é calculado (no exemplo abaixo estou usando PDO):

```
$NUMERO_DE_CLIENTES_POR_BLOCO = 10;

$numeroClientes = $pdo->query("SELECT count(*) FROM clientes")->fetchColumn();
$blocoAtual = intval($numeroClientes/$NUMERO_DE_CLIENTES_POR_BLOCO) + 1;
$cliente = [ ':nome' => 'Joao', ':bloco' => $blocoAtual ];

$inserirCliente = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO clientes (nome, bloco) VALUES (:nome, :bloco)");
$inserirCliente->exec($cliente);
```

Comment: Funcionou! Mas tive que mudar para `$inserirCliente->execute($cliente);`

Comment: Como faço neste caso, para dar um *UPDATE* nos registros que já existem?